# How to remove the mean of some values in the 3rd dimension of a matrix?

Tags: python, matlab, python-3.6

I have been stuck trying to do this with numpy with no luck. I am trying to move from MATLAB to Python, however, the transition hasn't been so easy. Anyway, that doesn't matter.

I am trying to code the Python analog of this simple MATLAB line of code:

```
  A(:,:,condtype==1 & Mat(:,9)==contra(ii)) = A(:,:, condtype ==1 & Mat(:,9)==contra(ii))-mean(A(:,:, condtype ==1 & Mat(:,9)==contra(ii)),3);
```

Right, so the above convoluted line of code does the following. Indexes a condition which is half of the 3rd dimension of A and removes the mean of those indexes which simultaneously changing the values in A to the new mean removed values.

How would one go about doing this in Python?

Comment: I would start by splitting out the line into parts. It's really hard to read that line, which doesn't make for maintainable code.

Comment: Are you using NumPy?

Comment: yes i am using NumPy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured it out. I was trying to use and when I should have been using np.isequal. Also, I needed to use `keepdims=True` for the mean. Here it is for anyone that wants to see:

```
def RmContrastMean(targettype,trialsMat,Contrastlvls,dX):
    present = targettype==1
    absent = targettype==0
    for i in range(0,Contrastlvls.size):
        CurrentContrast = trialsMat[:,8]==Contrastlvls[i]
        preIdx = np.equal(present, CurrentContrast)
        absIdx = np.equal(absent, CurrentContrast)
        #mean
        dX[:,:,preIdx] = dX[:,:,preIdx]-np.mean(dX[:,:,preIdx],axis=2,keepdims=True)
        dX[:,:,absIdx] = dX[:,:,absIdx]-np.mean(dX[:,:,absIdx],axis=2,keepdims=True)
        #std
        dX[:,:,preIdx] = dX[:,:,preIdx]/np.std(dX[:,:,preIdx],axis=2,keepdims=True)
        dX[:,:,absIdx] = dX[:,:,absIdx]/np.std(dX[:,:,absIdx],axis=2,keepdims=True)
    return dX
```

Comment: The variables in your question and your answer do not correspond at all. You may want to consider editing either to make sure they correspond to each other.